# Unintended Text in civiBooking Resource Configuration

Tags: civibooking

in civiBooking, additional text is showing under Resource Configurations while trying to add a booking.

Trying to add a booking, all the options (Conference Room/Hourly -$50, Conference Room/Daily -$200, Hourly - $50, Daily - $200) have the additional text /Phone or /Email added. [image]

Neither Phone or Email was set up as part of the resource configuration (Image 2) or size units (image 3). Where is it coming from? How do I get rid of it?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that text is likely from the "Resource configuration size unit" option list.

From the Resource Configuration Set page (**civicrm/admin/resource/config_set?reset=1**), you can edit the individual options for the configuration set in question. You can select a different "Unit" on the options, which shows up at the end of the selection as you noticed.

If there is no appropriate option listed, you can also edit the option list that is used here. Go to **Administer > System Settings > Option Groups** and look for the **Resource configuration size unit** group.

It looks like you've already set these values correctly. Did you change the values at some point? If you create a new "size unit" and select that, does it affect the display?

Comment: I am using the latest version. I guess I am assuming I have done something wrong, rather than that the ext is incorrect

Comment: I haven't used CiviBooking extensively but do have a site that I was going to do some testing with to see if it would fill a need. I'll try to do that in the next day or two and see if I see anything that helps here.

Comment: @LaurynnLowe I edited the answer above. Does that help?

Comment: hi Laryn, I haven't changed the values. But out of curiosity, I created new size unit/resource/config set. Now SMS is added to the config set.

Comment: So it seems to be pulling the options from the "Preferred Communication Method" option group instead of the "Resource configuration size unit" option group?!

Comment: yes? if so that would be a bug. but it seems someone else would have had had the same issue by now

Comment: Unless there was an issue with your install or upgrade process at some point. I'm not seeing it in the install I was working on the other day. Maybe the Github issue queue is the right place to go to ask for pointers, after all. Perhaps a simple option group ID setting that can be tweaked directly in the database to point it to the right option group.

Comment: https://github.com/compucorp/civibooking/issues/166